# Вывести числа из массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую! Как можно реализовать вывод чисел из массива по клику? Причём цифры нужно выводить по одному и по порядку. Пробовал через куки и php, но получилась шляпа.

Comment: "Пробовал" - где?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var my_array = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ],
  $button = $('#button').html("1й элемент массива из " + my_array.length),
  i = 0;

function arrayStep() {
  if (i < my_array.length) {
    $('body').append("<p style=\"background-color:green;color:white\">" + my_array[i] + "</p>");
    i++;
  }
  $button.html(i + "й элемент массива из " + my_array.length);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" onclick="arrayStep();">0й элемент массива из</button>
```